# Rails locations - where do I locate a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

In Rails -

Where should I locate Gems? I downloaded bootstrap and it's working, as well as a sample Rails app, separately, but I want them to work together. There is a `bootstrapped rails` gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrapped-rails) which I downloaded, but I'm unsure as to where I should locate it. Under `models`? 
And how do I make sure I am referring to it? I need to add something in `controller` as well?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Thanks. But where do I put it inside the app? does it automatically go to the relevant places or do I need to make sure it is located in model (or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 2):

Again, more an answer to the question in the title than to what was intended by the questioner but you can use

```
bundle show <gemname>
```

To locate the directory where a gem is installed.

Answer (score 1):

As Dfr mentioned: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Twitter bootstrap isn't anything more than (mostly) a collection of css/js/image files.

Add this to your gemfile

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

run

```
bundle install
```

run for simple css

```
rails generate bootstrap:install static
```

It should place relevant js and css files into your application.js and application.css files accordingly. (Read more about asset pipeline)

To get you started, in the gem's link under section - "Generating layouts and views", you can see rake tasks to generate sample layouts.

e.g.

```
rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
```

You should now have a twitter-bootstraped application.html.erb file under views/layouts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, you can locate your gems by running `gem env` in the console. That will give you the specific information about your "RubyGems Environment:" When you run `gem install some_gem_name` it will add this gem to your system.

However, what it sounds like your trying to do is add a `gem` to your app. If this is the case you add gems to a rails application's `Gemfile`.

So using your example, you'd locate your Gemfile and add the following:

```
gem "bootstrapped-rails", "~> 2.0.8.5"
```

Once that's done, you run `bundle install` in your terminal.

I find that a good resource for basic rails information can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
The tutorial is short and it will give you a great starting point.